# How to make this HTML code not go to another line

Tags: html, xhtml

This is my code so far:

```
<form>
    <p>Username: </p><input type="text" name="username" />
    <p>Password: </p><input type="text" name="password" />
    <br /><input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

For some interesting reason it is going to another line for ever paragraph and textbox. What can I do to prevent that?

Comment: Ummm...that's what paragraphs do by default.  You can either remove the paragraph tags or move things around via CSS (eg by assigning the `<p>` tags in question to their own class and  having your CSS say that those paragraph classes should be displayed in-line).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your paragraph tags around the input also. The P tag basically does a line break at the end of itself.

```
<form>
    <p>Username: <input type="text" name="username" /></p>
    <p>Password: <input type="text" name="password" /></p>
    <br /><input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
<form>
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" />
<br/>
    Password: <input type="text" name="password" />
<br /><input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

or

```
<form>
    Username:<br/> <input type="text" name="username" />
<br/>
    Password:<br/> <input type="text" name="password" />
<br /><input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
  <div style="float: left;">Username: <input type="text" name="username" /></div>
  <div style="float: left;">Password: <input type="text" name="password" /></div>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

They're dropping to a new line because of your markup. Paragraph (`<p>`) tags drop to a new line, as do breaks (`<br>`). I would suggest using `<span>` tags in place of the paragraph tags, and remove the line break.

Answer (score 0):

p tag is by default "display: block" which means a <br /> before and after p is added by the browser, so is the reason it is going to the next line.

include both the label & textbox in "p"

```
<form>
<p>Username: <input type="text" name="username" /></p>
<p>Password: <input type="text" name="password" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
```